# A problem about the squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let us have $a(x)<b(x)$ in which both a and b are real numbers.
Let's consider $a,b>0$. If $\lim{b(x)}=0$ then we conclude that $\lim{a(x)}=0$. Is it because $0<a(x)<b(x)$ and since $\lim{a(x)}$ is between two zero limits a's limit should be zero.

So In advanced calculus when I'm givin to sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ s.t $a_n<b_n$ we immediately conclude that if lim of $b_n$ goes to 0, then $\lim{a_n}=0$ But isn't this contradictory to the squeeze theorem since we need to make sure $ a_n$ is positive for $n>N$?

We need to make sure $a_n$ is positive right?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "we immediately conclude that if lim of $b_n$ goes to lim $a_n=0$"

Comment: Do you mean: you know $a_n < b_n$ and $\lim b_n = 0$... does that imply $\lim a_n = 0$?  If that's your question, the answer is no (need to know that $a_n\geq 0$).  It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $a_n$ needs to be non-negative, at least for $n$ large enough. Otherwise you could take $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, $a_n=-n$. Obviously, $a_n<b_n$ and $b_n\to 0$ but you don't have $a_n\to 0$.

Most of the time in calculus $a_n$ is the absolute value of something (of a difference between two quantities) and we seek some $b_n$ larger than $a_n$ and that goes to $0$.